# NameError in Python when listing static attributes from within same class

Tags: python, static-variables

I have the following python class:

```
class list_stuff:    
        A = 'a'
        B = 'b'
        C = 'c'
        stufflist = [v for k,v in list_stuff.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("__")]
```

But it shows a NameError saying undefined variable `list_stuff`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685828/python-2-7-how-to-get-the-list-of-static-variables-in-a-class), it should work.

I also tried with:

```
list_stuff().__dict__.items()
```

But still same error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058305/getting-attributes-of-a-class

Comment: seems difficult from the inside.

Comment: Nonsense. Undefined variables aren't syntax errors.

Comment: it's a NameError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
class list_stuff:    
    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'
    C = 'c'

    @classmethod
    def stufflist(cls):
        return [v for k,v in cls.list_stuff.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("__")]
```

which has the same effect as my original intent.

Thanks all for quick replies.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you cannot reference the class in the class body.
The issue I see here is that you are referring to the class `list_stuff` within the class definition. To resolve simply move that line outside the class:

```
class list_stuff:    
    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'
    C = 'c'

stufflist = [v for k,v in list_stuff.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("__")]
```

Here is the [documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: That works. But I wanted to keep it inside the class, so i ended up using a @classmethod, then referenced the classname with cls.list_stuff. This gives me the same effect I wanted originally.

Comment: That’s true you could do it achieve what you want that way! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the indentation, as you are essentially calling the class from within.

Try this:

```
class list_stuff:    
    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'
    C = 'c'
stufflist = [v for k,v in list_stuff.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("__")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that would generate the list attribute you wish. First you will need to generate an instance of that class, before running the `get_list()` method.

```
class list_stuff():
    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'
    C = 'c'  

def get_list(self):
    self.thelist = [v for k,v in list_stuff.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("__")]
    return self.thelist

list_a = list_stuff()
print list_a.get_list()
print list_a.thelistenter code here
```

This is what it returns:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', <function get_list at 0x7f07d6c63668>]
['a', 'b', 'c', <function get_list at 0x7f07d6c63668>]
```